# GCC/LD Only link against direct dependencies

Tags: c++, linux, g++, ld

I have scenario where I have a binary that depends on library A which in turn depends on library B.

I have built library A against library B, but none of library B:s symbols leak out of library A, everything is contained in the cpp-file.

Now I only want to link the binary against library A, since all of the symbols found in the binary can be satisfied by library A. Is this possible?

In the real application, library B is an implementation of a network protocol and I have a lot of binaries who link against the intermediate library. And I don't want the binaries to be aware of the different network protocols used.

Platform: Linux / GCC

Code:

liba/liba.h:

```
#ifndef LIBA_H
#define LIBA_H

int getANumber();

#endif
```

liba/liba.cpp:

```
#include "liba.h"
#include "../libb/libb.h"

int getANumber(){ return getBNumber(); }
```

libb/libb.h:

```
#ifndef LIBB_H
#define LIBB_H

int getBNumber();

#endif
```

libb/libb.cpp:

```
#include "libb.h"

int getBNumber(){ return 42; }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "liba/liba.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << getANumber() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

commands:

```
~/libb/ $ g++ -shared -o libb.so libb.cpp
~/liba/ $ g++ -shared -o liba.so liba.cpp -L../libb -lb

~/ $ g++ -o main main.cpp -Lliba -la # fails

~/ # These two work, but I don't want to specify libb here.
~/ $ g++ -o main main.cpp -Lliba -la -Wl,-rpath-link,libb 
~/ $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=libb g++ -o main main.cpp -Lliba -la
```

What is the best way to solve this? Do I have to create it as a plugin?

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Make `libb` a static library? Or use the complicated linking commands...

Comment: In fact, it looks like all you need to do is tell LD_LIBRARY_PATH where the `libb` is - sounds like the right solution to me.

Comment: I want to be able to change libb between different versions at runtime, so I can't make it static.

Yes, the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** version works, but I would prefer to leave it until runtime for resolution since I don't know what version I will be using. Of course, the ABI can't change, so perhaps any version is good to make the linker happy. I just think that it should be possible to tell the linker to not try to resolve symbols recursively through the dependency chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to CHANGE which library you use at runtime, then you can't link against it directly, but use a "manual" loading. In other words, call [`dlopen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [`dlsym`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man3/dlopen.3.html)

This probably also means that you need a slightly different architecture in "liba", since each function in "libb" becomes a function pointer, so something along these lines:

```
int (*getBNumber)() = NULL;

void initialize()
{
   void *handle = dlopen("libb", RTLD_NOW); 
   getBNumber = (int (*)())dlsym(handle, "getBNumber"); 
}

int getANumber(){ return getBNumber(); }
```

You'll need to set something up to call initialize at some point - or have a `if (!initialized) initialize();` in each function.

Comment: My bad, I meant when starting the program, not during execution. But perhaps it's best to go all the way and create a proxy. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to change it "after you compiled", you need to use the method I describe above.

Comment: As long as it's dynamically linked, you can change the library after compilation as long as they have the same filename/soname and all symbols are resolved.

Comment: Yes, but it requires (at least) changing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, probably also clearing some caches (and possibly that the same library isn't loaded somewhere else).